# Передать переменные типа структура в функцию, находящуюся в другом cpp

Tags: c++

Как можно нужно объявить функцию использующую аргументы типа структуры.
На примере:
Имеем структуру:

```
 struct polygon {

    point *polygon_ = new point;
    size_t size_polygon;

    polygon(point polygon_[], size_t size_polygon) {
        this->polygon_ = polygon_;
        this->size_polygon = size_polygon;
    }

};
```

Каким образом я могу использовать `polygon P` в функции, которая находится в другом cpp?

```
void fisrt(polygon P)
{

}
```

Comment: Только подключением `#include "main.cpp"`, в котором расположена данная структура?

Comment: Вынесите объявление структуры в заголовочный файл и подключайте его везде, где требуется эта структура.

Comment: Объявить структуру в заголовочном файле и включать в те .cpp, в которые нужно. Если вы начнеите включать .cpp-файлы - нарветесь на массу неприятностей, связанную с one definition rule...